# How to declare "propTypes" for styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-proptypes

I am developing a react library, say `MyLib`, so I want to provide `propTypes` for my lib consumers. However, in combination of typescript and styled-components, this leads to the following error:

```
Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'StyledComponent<"div", any, ScrollerProp, never>'.ts(2339)
```

According to the following code base, what type should I declare for `Scroller`?
(Currently I can only use `any` type to resolve compile error)

#### MyLib.d.ts

```
export type ScrollerProp = {
  maxHeight: number,
}
```

#### MyLib.tsx

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Scroller: any = styled.div<ScrollerProp>`
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  ${({ maxHeight }) => maxHeight && css`
    max-height: ${maxHeight}px;
  `}
`

Scroller.propTypes = {
  maxHeight: PropTypes.number,
}
```

Comment: You may be able to pass additional types to be extended from to the `styled` function:
`const Scroller = styled<{ propTypes: any}>`

Comment: TS saying that the property PropTypes does not exists in your Scroller Object. You don't need to use `Scroller.PropTypes`

Comment: @ufollettu but I need `propTypes` for those non-typescript user to validate prop types

Comment: @RobertCooper this is not working

Answer (score 1):

I had simillar, if not the same problem. What worked for me was:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Scroller: any = styled.div<{maxHeight: number}>`
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  ${({ maxHeight }) => maxHeight && css`
    max-height: ${maxHeight}px;
  `}
`
```

Using my type as externally defined did not work, but putting it directly worked. As per [Styled components Docs - Using custom props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ScrollerStyle: any = styled.div<ScrollerProp>`
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  ${({ maxHeight }) => maxHeight && css`
    max-height: ${maxHeight}px;
  `}
`;

const Scroller = (props: any) => <ScrollerStyle {...props} />;

Scroller.propTypes = {
  maxHeight: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Note: I barely know TS, so I'm not sure if the 'props: ' part is correct, but you get the gist.